# Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tendo um problema ao tentar salvar um pdf utilizando a biblioteca "pdf_dart".
Presumo que o problema esteja vinculado a imagem que estou baixando da internet para tentar anexar ao pdf mas não sei ao certo o que é.

### CÓDIGO

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:app_formulario/models/Customer.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart' as pdfDart;
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageDart;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as materialDart;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PDFBloc {
  PDFBloc() {
    final Document pdf = Document();

    http
        .get(
            "https://clsp.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-clsp-500px.png")
        .then((onValue) {
      final image = pdfDart.PdfImage(
        pdf.document,
        image: onValue.bodyBytes,
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
      );

      pdf.addPage(Page(build: (Context context) {
        return Center(
          child: Image(image),
        ); // Center
      }));

      criarPDF(pdf);
    });
  }

void criarPDF(Document pdf) async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    appDocPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rwrd.app_formulario";

    final File file = File('$appDocPath/example.pdf');
    file.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save());
  }
```

O erro acontece bem no momento em que vou salvar o pdf já com a imagem ou seja, aparentemente a imagem é baixada normalmente, porém ao inseri-lá no pdf e tentar salvar é ocasionado o erro.

Não sei se a forma que estou salvando é a correta, talvez seja isso, mas infelizmente não consigo acessar a pasta do arquivo sem ser passando o caminho todo onde será salvo (se me derem uma solução para isso também ficaria grato mas não é o maior problema em questão).

### A STACKTRACE DO ERRO

```
E/flutter (18670): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 6307: 6308
E/flutter (18670): #0      Uint8List.[]  (dart:typed_data-patch/typed_data_patch.dart:2209:7)
E/flutter (18670): #1      PdfImage._prepare 
package:pdf/src/image.dart:183
E/flutter (18670): #2      PdfObject._write 
package:pdf/src/object.dart:53
E/flutter (18670): #3      PdfOutput.write 
package:pdf/src/output.dart:69
E/flutter (18670): #4      SetMixin.forEach  (dart:collection/set.dart:148:30)
E/flutter (18670): #5      PdfDocument._write 
package:pdf/src/document.dart:168
E/flutter (18670): #6      PdfDocument.save 
package:pdf/src/document.dart:176
E/flutter (18670): #7      Document.save 
package:pdf/widgets/document.dart:71
E/flutter (18670): #8      PDFBloc.criarPDF 
package:app_formulario/blocs/pdfBloc.dart:53
E/flutter (18670): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18670): #9      new PDFBloc.<anonymous closure> 
package:app_formulario/blocs/pdfBloc.dart:35
E/flutter (18670): #10     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
E/flutter (18670): #11     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (18670): #12     _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
E/flutter (18670): #13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
E/flutter (18670): #14     Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
E/flutter (18670): #15     Future._completeWithValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
E/flutter (18670): #16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:32:15)
E/flutter (18670): #17     _completeOnAsyncReturn  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:290:13)
E/flutter (18670): #18     _withClient (package:http/http.dart)
E/flutter (18670): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18670): #19     get 
package:http/http.dart:46
E/flutter (18670): #20     new PDFBloc 
package:app_formulario/blocs/pdfBloc.dart:18
E/flutter (18670): #21     FormBloc._recoverCustomerInformations 
package:app_formulario/blocs/formBloc.dart:37
E/flutter (18670): #22     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
E/flutter (18670): #23     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (18670): #24     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (18670): #25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
E/flutter (18670): #26     _DelayedData.perform  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:593:14)
E/flutter (18670): #27     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:709:11)
E/flutter (18670): #28     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:669:7)
E/flutter (18670): #29     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
E/flutter (18670): #30     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (18670): #31     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (18670): #32     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (18670): #33     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter (18670): #34     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (18670): #35     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (18670): #36     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (18670): #37     _microtaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (18670): #38     _startMicrotaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
E/flutter (18670):
```

Fiz um teste recentemente e percebei que o problema está porque eu tento salvar o pdf dentro do "then" do retorno da imagem.

O erro não está necessariamente ligado a imagem (não sei se essa informação é útil).

Se alguém puder me mostrar uma outra alternativa para recuperar uma imagem, seja da internet ou seja do "assets" e conseguir pôr no pdf eu ficaria grato.

Comment: @Drinjer é sim :/

Comment: Tentou com alguma outra imagem? Com tamanho(bytes) menor

Comment: Tentei sim Drinjer.

Eu ainda não descobri o problema, mas não está totalmente relacionado com a imagem (igual comentei ali embaixo).

Quando eu tento criar o PDF "DENTRO" do "Then" do http, dá esse problema.

Não importa se há imagem ou não.

Comment: Tente exibir a imagem em tela normalmente, em um `Container`, `Image` ou algo do tipo, para ver se realmente ela está sendo retornada corretamente.